# Reapply selection for the same region in Plotly.js

Tags: javascript, charts, plotly

There is a plot with one trace disabled:
[image]
Then user select some points using lasso:
[image]
And then enables the "trace 1" clicking the legend
[image]

Is it possible to get those "new" points from trace 1 in code?